# How to remove duplicate input messages using Kakfa stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic wherein I get a burst of events from various devices. There are n number of devices which emit weather report every s seconds.

The problem is that these devices emit 5-10 records of the same value every s seconds. So if you see the output in the kafka topic for a single device, it is as follows:-

For device1:-
t1,t1,t1,t1(in the same moment, then gap of s seconds)t2,t2,t2,t2(then gap of s seconds),t3,t3,t3,t3

However, I want to remove these duplicate records in kafka that come as burst of events.
I want to consume as follows:-
t1,t2,t3,...

I was trying to use concepts of windowing and ktable that Kafka stream API provide, but it doesn't seem possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think, it's called "flatten"...

Comment: You might want to use Processor API and punctuations: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I was trying to avoid the processor API. Is there no way to do this using kafka streams DSL?

Comment: Why do you try to avoid it? It's actually not hard to use. For the DSL, the is no guarantee that you can de-duplicate all events -- you can use KTables and caches to reduce the number of duplicates only.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Kafka's Log compaction. But in order to use it you should  have the same key for all the duplicated messages, and a different key for non duplicate messages. Have a look at this.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Comment: can you please elaborate on this approach? think this will probably need to keep 'log-retention-ms' same as 's' which is Kafka property.

Comment: You need to configure log.cleanup.policy=compact property and set log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms property to 0 for immediate compaction. The above mentioned link has a detailed explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to read the topic into a KTable using t as the key. The duplicated values would be treated as upserts rather than inserts which would effectively drop them. Then write the KTable into another topic

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1:

Produce the same key with all messages, that are logically duplicates.

#### Step 2:

If you don't need near real-time processing with this topic as an input, use `cleanup.policy=compact`. It will produce "eventual" deduplication (may be delayed for a long time).

Otherwise, use exactly-once kafka streams deduplication. Here are [DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940728/10724963) and [Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55810617/10724963) examples.