# How to handle duplicate messages using Kafka streaming DSL functions

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My requirement is to skip or avoid duplicate messages(having same key) received from INPUT Topic using kafka stream DSL API.

There is possibility of source system sending duplicate messages to INPUT topic in case of any failures.

FLOW -

Source System --> INPUT Topic --> Kafka Streaming --> OUTPUT Topic

Currently I am using flatMap to generate multiple keys out the payload but flatMap is stateless so not able to avoid duplicate message processing upon receiving from INPUT Topic.

I am looking for DSL API which can skip duplicate records received from INPUT Topic and also generate multiple key/values before sending to OUTPUT Topic.

Thought Exactly Once configuration will be useful here to deduplicate messages received from INPUT Topic based on keys but looks like its not working, probably I did not understand usage of Exactly Once.

Could you please put some light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My requirement is to skip or avoid duplicate messages(having same key) received from INPUT Topic using kafka stream DSL API.

Take a look at the `EventDeduplication` example at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples, which does that. You can then adapt the example with the required `flatMap` functionality that is specific to your use case.

Here's the gist of the example:

```java
final KStream<byte[], String> input = builder.stream(inputTopic);
final KStream<byte[], String> deduplicated = input.transform(
    // In this example, we assume that the record value as-is represents a unique event ID by
    // which we can perform de-duplication.  If your records are different, adapt the extractor
    // function as needed.
    () -> new DeduplicationTransformer<>(windowSize.toMillis(), (key, value) -> value),
    storeName);
deduplicated.to(outputTopic);
```

and

```java
    /**
     * @param maintainDurationPerEventInMs how long to "remember" a known event (or rather, an event
     *                                     ID), during the time of which any incoming duplicates of
     *                                     the event will be dropped, thereby de-duplicating the
     *                                     input.
     * @param idExtractor extracts a unique identifier from a record by which we de-duplicate input
     *                    records; if it returns null, the record will not be considered for
     *                    de-duping but forwarded as-is.
     */
    DeduplicationTransformer(final long maintainDurationPerEventInMs, final KeyValueMapper<K, V, E> idExtractor) {
      if (maintainDurationPerEventInMs < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maintain duration per event must be >= 1");
      }
      leftDurationMs = maintainDurationPerEventInMs / 2;
      rightDurationMs = maintainDurationPerEventInMs - leftDurationMs;
      this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
      this.context = context;
      eventIdStore = (WindowStore<E, Long>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
    }

    public KeyValue<K, V> transform(final K key, final V value) {
      final E eventId = idExtractor.apply(key, value);
      if (eventId == null) {
        return KeyValue.pair(key, value);
      } else {
        final KeyValue<K, V> output;
        if (isDuplicate(eventId)) {
          output = null;
          updateTimestampOfExistingEventToPreventExpiry(eventId, context.timestamp());
        } else {
          output = KeyValue.pair(key, value);
          rememberNewEvent(eventId, context.timestamp());
        }
        return output;
      }
    }

    private boolean isDuplicate(final E eventId) {
      final long eventTime = context.timestamp();
      final WindowStoreIterator<Long> timeIterator = eventIdStore.fetch(
          eventId,
          eventTime - leftDurationMs,
          eventTime + rightDurationMs);
      final boolean isDuplicate = timeIterator.hasNext();
      timeIterator.close();
      return isDuplicate;
    }

    private void updateTimestampOfExistingEventToPreventExpiry(final E eventId, final long newTimestamp) {
      eventIdStore.put(eventId, newTimestamp, newTimestamp);
    }

    private void rememberNewEvent(final E eventId, final long timestamp) {
      eventIdStore.put(eventId, timestamp, timestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
      // Note: The store should NOT be closed manually here via `eventIdStore.close()`!
      // The Kafka Streams API will automatically close stores when necessary.
    }

  }
```

> I am looking for DSL API which can skip duplicate records received from INPUT Topic and also generate multiple key/values before sending to OUTPUT Topic.

The DSL doesn't include such functionality out of the box, but the example above shows how you can easily build your own de-duplication logic by combining the DSL with the Processor API of Kafka Streams, with the use of `Transformers`.

> Thought Exactly Once configuration will be useful here to deduplicate messages received from INPUT Topic based on keys but looks like its not working, probably I did not understand usage of Exactly Once.

As Matthias J. Sax mentioned in his answer, from Kafka's perspective these "duplicates" are not duplicates from the point of view of its exactly-once processing semantics. Kafka ensures that it will not introduce any such duplicates itself, but it cannot make such decisions out-of-the-box for upstream data sources, which are black box for Kafka.

Comment: When I try your above suggestion with the example I get - ```error: transform(K#1,V#1) in DeduplicationTransformer cannot implement transform(K#2,V#2) in ValueTransformerWithKey
        public KeyValue<K, V> transform(final K key, final V value) {
                              ^ ```

Comment: Please ask a separate question with more details about your exact code, Kafka version, etc.

Comment: Here is a link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720007/kafka-finding-distinct-events-based-on-keyvalue

Comment: Hi, the provided example is working fine, but what if we wanted to forward downstream only the last occuring event and not the first one?

Answer (score 2):

It's achievable with DSL only as well, using [SessionWindows](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/SessionWindows.html) changelog without caching.

1. Wrap the value with `duplicate` flag
2. Turn the flag to `true` in `reduce()` within time window
3. Filter out `true` flag values
4. Unwrap the original key and value

#### Topology:

```
Serde<K> keySerde = ...;
Serde<V> valueSerde = ...;
Duration dedupWindowSize = ...;
Duration gracePeriod = ...;
DedupValueSerde<V> dedupValueSerde = new DedupValueSerde<>(valueSerde);

new StreamsBuilder()
    .stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerde))
    .mapValues(v -> new DedupValue<>(v, false))
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(SessionWindows.ofInactivityGapAndGrace(dedupWindowSize, gracePeriod))
    .reduce(
        (value1, value2) -> new DedupValue<>(value1.value(), true),
        Materialized
            .<K, DedupValue<V>, SessionStore<Bytes, byte[]>>with(keySerde, dedupValueSerde)
            .withCachingDisabled()
    )
    .toStream()
    .filterNot((wk, dv) -> dv == null || dv.duplicate())
    .selectKey((wk, dv) -> wk.key())
    .mapValues(DedupValue::value)
    .to("output-topic", Produced.with(keySerde, valueSerde));
```

#### Value wrapper:

```
record DedupValue<V>(V value, boolean duplicate) { }
```

#### Value wrapper SerDe (example):

```
public class DedupValueSerde<V> extends WrapperSerde<DedupValue<V>> {

  public DedupValueSerde(Serde<V> vSerde) {
    super(new DvSerializer<>(vSerde.serializer()), new DvDeserializer<>(vSerde.deserializer()));
  }

  private record DvSerializer<V>(Serializer<V> vSerializer) implements Serializer<DedupValue<V>> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, DedupValue<V> data) {
      byte[] vBytes = vSerializer.serialize(topic, data.value());
      return ByteBuffer
          .allocate(vBytes.length + 1)
          .put(data.duplicate() ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0)
          .put(vBytes)
          .array();
    }
  }

  private record DvDeserializer<V>(Deserializer<V> vDeserializer) implements Deserializer<DedupValue<V>> {

    @Override
    public DedupValue<V> deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
      boolean duplicate = buffer.get() == (byte) 1;
      int remainingSize = buffer.remaining();
      byte[] vBytes = new byte[remainingSize];
      buffer.get(vBytes);
      V value = vDeserializer.deserialize(topic, vBytes);
      return new DedupValue<>(value, duplicate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is pretty interesting

Comment: This solution is brilliant. Works like a charm. Pretty unsure about the performances since we're introducing rebalancing operations. Probably someone more expert than me can say something more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly-once can be use to ensure that consuming and processing an input topic, does not result in duplicates in the output topic. However, from an exactly-once point of view, the duplicates in the input topic that you describe are not really duplicates but two regular input messages.

For remove input topic duplicates, you can use a `transform()` step with an attached state store (there is no built-in operator in the DSL that does what you want). For each input records, you first check if you find the corresponding key in the store. If not, you add it to the store and forward the message. If you find it in the store, you drop the input as duplicate. Note, this will only work with 100% correctness guarantee if you enable exactly-once processing in your Kafka Streams application. Otherwise, even if you try do deduplicate, Kafka Streams could re-introduce duplication in case of a failure.

Additionally, you need to decide how long you want to keep entries in the store. You could use a `Punctuation` to remove old data from the store if you are sure that no further duplicate can be in the input topic. One way to do this, would be to store the record timestamp (or maybe offset) in the store, too. This way, you can compare the current time with the store record time within `punctuate()` and delete old records (ie, you would iterator over all entries in the store via `store#all()`).

After the `transform()` you apply your `flatMap()` (or could also merge your `flatMap()` code into `transform()` directly.

Comment: Hi, Could you pleas help me to understand "Kafka Streams could re-introduce duplication in case of a failure"? As Streams do record by record processing,. if there is a failure, will there be only one duplicate message at any point of time?

Comment: There could be more the one duplicate (or missing data, depending how you implement de-duplication) in case of failure for at-least-once processing. Even if we do record-by-record processing, the progress is only record periodically (ie, each 30 seconds by default -> `commit.interval.ms` config).