# Kafka Streams: send only the first message within a window downstream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement data deduplication using Kafka streams. Basically, I'd like to drop any duplicates after the first encountered message in a session window with a 1-second size and an 8-hour grace period for late arrivals.

A more concrete example:

Input:

```
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:22.555 }
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.876 }
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.574 }
Key: B2; Value: { sensor: B2, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:24.732 }
```

Desired output:

```
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:22.555 }
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.876 }
Key: B2; Value: { sensor: B2, current: 52, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:24.732 }
```

so the third message

```
{ sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.574 }
```

from the input stream should be dropped since the sensor and current fields are matching what we already have in a defined 1 second window

Here's sample code:

```kotlin
    streamsBuilder
      .stream(
        "input-topic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), telemetrySerde)
          // set AVRO record as ingestion timestamp
          .withTimestampExtractor(ValueTimestampExtractor()) 
      )
      .groupBy(
        { _, value ->
          TelemetryDuplicate(
            sensor = value.sensor,
            current = value.current
          )
        },
        Grouped.with(telemetryDuplicateSerde, telemetrySerde)
      )
      .windowedBy(
        SessionWindows.ofInactivityGapAndGrace(
          /* inactivityGap = */ Duration.ofSeconds(1),
          /* afterWindowEnd = */ Duration.ofHours(8)
        )
      )
      // always keep only the first record of the group
      .reduce { value, _ -> value } 
      .toStream()
      .selectKey { k, _ -> k.key().sensor }
      .to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), telemetrySerde))
```

it is actually working and it does the job, HOWEVER, despite that I rekey the resulting stream from windowed to just sensor id, I have the following messages in the `output-topic`:

```
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:22.555 }
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.876 }
Key: A1; Value: NULL
Key: A1; Value: { sensor: A1, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:23.876 }
Key: B2; Value: { sensor: B2, current: 42, timestamp: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:59:24.732 }
```

That means that the stream is actually de-duplicated, but in a quite awkward way: due to the change in the session window it produces a tombstone that cancels the previous aggregation despite that neither the selected key nor the value are changed (see how `reduce` is defined).

The question: is it possible to somehow produce only *the first* encountered record in the window and not produce any tombstones and "updated" aggregations?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to remove the null values from being produced to your result topic:

```
...
.selectKey { k, _ -> k.key().sensor }
.filter { _, value -> value != null}
.to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), telemetrySerde))
```

Comment: In this case, won’t it just remove the tombstones while keep sending the updated aggregations? And I will end up with duplicates in the output topic?

Comment: yes, indeed it would. I missed that detail in your question, that it was sending the record + the tombstone. So in this cases when I couldn't use the windowing directly to achieve what I needed what I usually do is to attach a processor or transform step where you will have full control over the records.

Comment: Could you please give a hint on how to use processors or transforms in this case, because it looks like I will need to implement my own session windowing mechanism + storage to support late arrivals...

Comment: Yes, you might need to change your topology a bit. You can always use a KTable on the stream before attaching the processor and then the local storage will be "managed" for you and in the processor you can access that storage to check if the event is duplicated and then discard it if it is. Specifically about deduplication there's a nice example in the confluent github examples repo for streams. I hope it helps you -> https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I wonder how this solution will work with larger windows (like 8 hours in my example) cause here RAM & Disk usage might be a concern already, given enough throughput. And especially historical data re-processing use case when we can have the incoming data for several months in mere minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the example of `SessionWindows` deduplication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940728/10724963).